# Mount vs automount systemd units: which one to use for what?

Tags: systemd, automounting, systemd-mount

After doing some research about systemd units, I found two different kinds of mount unit: the `.mount` and the `.automount`. At first, it seemed logical to me that the `automount` unit would mount a `mount` automatically. However, as it turns out, when you enable a mount unit:

```bsh
systemctl enable media-mydisk.mount
```

It will automatically be mounted at boot. I'm somewhat new to systemd, but this has been bugging me for quite some time already. I've also posted the code of the unit at the end.

So, my main question is: why does one need `automount`s if one can just enable a `mount` unit?

Here's my `media-mydisk.mount` if that makes any difference:

```
[Unit]
Description=My disk

[Mount]
What=/dev/sdb1
Where=/media/mydisk
Type=ext4
Options=defaults

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've searched the web but couldn't find any comparison between using an `.automount` and simply enabling a `.mount`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "auto" part in `automount` does not refer to the boot process: `automount` units define mount points that are mounted *on-demand*, i.e. only when they are accessed.

`automount` units are optional; but, when they exist, corresponding `mount` units must also exist. The former are meant to add functionalities to existing instances of the latter. From `man systemd.mount`:

> Optionally, a mount unit may be accompanied by an automount unit, to allow on-demand or parallelized mounting.

And, from `man systemd.automount`:

> For each automount unit file a matching mount unit file (see systemd.mount(5) for details) must exist which is activated when the automount path is accessed. Example: if an automount unit `home-lennart.automount` is active and the user accesses `/home/lennart` the mount unit `home-lennart.mount` will be activated.

A typical use case for `automount` units is mounting file systems (e.g. on remote or removable or encrypted media) that are not required during the boot process and may slow it down, or that may be unavailable at boot, but that you still like having managed by systemd.

A simple, illustrative-only example. Given the `mnt-foo.mount` unit

```
[Unit]
Description=foo mount

[Mount]
Where=/mnt/foo
What=/home/user/foo
Type=ext4
```

(for simplicity, `foo` is just a regular file formatted as ext4), and the `mnt-foo.automount` unit

```
[Unit]
Description=foo automount

[Automount]
Where=/mnt/foo

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after the latter is activated (or `enable`d, and the system rebooted)

```
# systemctl start mnt-foo.automount
```

you will be able to check that `/home/user/foo` is not mounted anywhere yet—`mount` gives

```
$ mount | grep foo
systemd-1 on /mnt/foo type autofs (...)
```

and indeed `/home/user/foo` is only mounted on `/mnt/foo` as soon as you access the mount point:

```
$ ls /mnt/foo
```

```
$ mount | grep foo
systemd-1 on /mnt/foo type autofs (...)
/home/user/foo on /mnt/foo type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it to me!
Alright, one more question: you mentioned one can use an automount for drives
>  that are not required during the boot process 
Does this mean that when `enable`ing a drive, it _must_ be mounted for the system to boot correctly? Or does this depend on the target or unit config?

Comment: @Linux4win Sorry for reposting, my previous comments had several typos. Not sure I'm understanding your question, but: 1) regardless of `automount` units, enabled `mount` units are only mounted at boot if they are needed (e.g. `WantedBy`) in order to reach the default target (in systemd parlance); if so, and if their resource is not available, 1.1) the system won't boot if they hold a needed part of the tree (e.g. `/`); 1.2) otherwise, their mount operation will fail, possibly slowing down the boot process. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) 2) A file system in an enabled _and activated_ (started) `automount` unit only needs to be available when accessed; it doesn't need to be available at boot. If an `automount` unit is not started, its file system is not mounted when the corresponding mount point is accessed. 3) Having both an enabled _and activated_ `mount` unit and a corresponding enabled and activated `automount` unit at boot makes only sense in corner cases that are beyond the scope of this answer, I guess (e.g. mounting a file system at boot and unmounting it when not used by means of the `TimeoutIdleSec` option).

Comment: I guess you would have to add a "nofail" to your options, since it is mount which will mount. The you can enable without fearing not being able to boot up. Now honor the effort and accept the answer. @Linux4Win